# Exclude certain beans when running a junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

So, I have the two following java test classes:

```
package com.company.alfresco;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BuildFileTreeApplication.class)
@Slf4j
public class BuildFileTreeTest {

    @Autowired
    private CmisDao cmisDao;

    @Autowired
    private AlfrescoFileTreeAPI alfrescoFileTreeAPI;

    ...
}
```

and

```
package com.company.facade;

@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class EntryPointTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{
    private Map<String, String> documentMetadata;

    @Autowired
    private FacadeInitializer facadeInitializer;

    ...
}
```

I also have two separate main method classes, one used by each test class:

```
package com.company;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company", "com.company.ssh", "com.company.camel",
"com.company.cmis.services", "com.company.facade"})
public class AlfrescoApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(AlfrescoApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.company;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.alfresco", "com.company.models",
    "com.company.config"})
public class BuildFileTreeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(BuildFileTreeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I want to run the first test (the `BuildFileTreeTest`), without using the bean that the other test is using (`FacadeInitializer`).

For some reason, using this package setup, when I am running the `BuildFileTreeTest` test class, the `FacadeInitializer` bean is still used in the application context, altough it is present in the "facade" package, which I didn't include in the `@ComponentScan` annotation, within the `BuildFileTreeApplication` spring main method class. Any ideas ?

Answer (score -2):

You can exclude beans with types, annotations etc.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.alfresco", "com.company.models", "com.company.config"},
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {FacadeInitializer.class})})
public class BuildFileTreeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BuildFileTreeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.alfresco", "com.company.models",
    "com.company.config"},
        excludeFilters =
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {FacadeInitializer.class}))`, but that bean is still used in the application context.

Comment: @NarcisNeacsu could you please give me more details about "that bean is still used". I've tested the solution and the bean will not be scanned at all.

Comment: Basically I am saying that an instance of `FacadeInitializer` is being created, and it is available for injection. It is not being ignored. I need to ignore this bean, because it depends on some external resource, that is not available at the moment, and I will get an exception, even if only the constructor is executed. Maybe I am missing something that I forgot to include in the description of the question.